# Checking if enter key pressed in the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code to check if enter key was pressed in textbox but I am getting 
type error **TypeError: e is undefined**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>demo</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
function memSort(e){        
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            alert("Enter was pressed ");
        }       
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="searchBox">
            <div class="keyname">Keyword : </div>          
            <input name="usersearch" id="usersearch" type="text" value="" onKeydown="memSort();"/>
            <div id="listOrders"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onKeydown="memSort(event);"`

Comment: Why you are using inline events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `event` object while calling JavaScript function like below :

```
<input name="usersearch" id="usersearch" type="text" value="" onKeydown="memSort(event);"/>
```

It is simple in jQuery and no need to call from input :

```
$('#usersearch').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
            alert("Enter was pressed ");
     }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input name="usersearch" id="usersearch" type="text" value="" onkeypress="memSort(event);"/>

function memSort(e){
 var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (key==13){
     alert("Enter was pressed ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using jQuery in your code. Then why not leverage the same for unobtrusive event handling.

```
$("usersearch").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
    ...
    }
});
```

Or if just using Javascript, pass the event object parameter:

```
onkeypress="memSort(event);"
```

But, inline handlers should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You must passing the `event` object, when call the function.

Try this:

HTML Code

```
<div class="searchBox">
    <div class="keyname">Keyword : </div>          
    <input name="usersearch" id="usersearch" type="text" value="" onKeydown="memSort(event);"/>
    <div id="listOrders"></div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qQhv/)

**"TypeError: e is undefined" - Explanation:**

**Notice the html code: onKeydown="memSort(event);**
Here i pass a event object `event` as function parameter. But in your code you missed this one. And when you are not passing a parameter it's refer as `undefined`. (if you not passed the event then you are not able to get the `e.keyCode`.) So, you must pass the event object.